# How to JSoup doc text with encoding

Tags: jsoup

I have a node like this

```
<div>&gt; something &lt;</div>
```

I need to get the text of the div element like this

```
&gt; something &lt;
```

What I get from .text() method, output is

```
> something <
```

In BeautifulSoup, it will return the `&gt; something &lt;` not encoded output.

How do I get the unconverted text from JSoup?

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
```

OR

use the Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) for this:

```
Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports HTML 4.0 entities.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From outputSettings how do I get the text? I couldn't figure that using docs.

Comment: you mean something like this : doc.body().html() ?